# route() helper function in a different locale

Tags: laravel, routes, internationalization, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a language switcher, so that you can easily change language on the fly (without being redirected to the home page).

The thing I can't seem to accomplish is getting a url from a route name in a different locale.

Imagine your on mydomain.com/events (or mydomain.com/en/events since these are the same) and I want to get url in french (mydomain.com/fr/evenements)...

In my routes.php I have:

```
$locale = Request::segment(1);
if ( !array_key_exists($locale, Config::get('translatable.languages'))) {
    $locale = null;
    App::setlocale(Config::get('translatable.fallback_locale'));
}else{
    App::setLocale($locale);
}

Route::group(array('prefix' => $locale), function(){
    Route::get(Lang::get('routes.events'), array('as' => 'events.index', 'uses' => 'EventController@index'));
});
```

I have tried

1. setting the application locale right before calling the `route($route_name)` helper function
2. Setting a session variable with the requested locale (in this example 'fr'), then calling the `route($route_name)` function. For this I also added at the top of routes.php:

   if( Session::has('requested_locale') ){
       $locale =  Session::pull('requested_locale');
   }

I have no idea's left on how to handle this...
I know there is a package Laravel Localization that can do this, but I need it to work without that package (if possible)...

Answer (score 2):

My solution on Laravel 5.1 was...

1. Defined locales in the config/app.php to create routes using the language files

   `'locale' => 'en',
   'locales' => [
       'en'=>'English',
       'fr'=>'Français'
   ],`
2. I've defined my routes in the resources/lang/ directory ('en/routes.php' and 'fr/routes.php' in my case)

   `return [
       'about' => 'a-propos',
   ];`
3. Defined routes using the language keys, example:

   `Route::get(trans('routes.about'), ['as' => 'about', function () {
       return view('pages.'.App::getLocale().'.about');
   }]);`
4. Then I've created dummy route that would be used only for switching to another locale, ONLY after the current route has been matched to request

`

```
Route::matched(function($route) {

    $route = Route::current();

    $route_name = $route->getName();
    $route_uri = $route->uri();

    $locales = Config::get('app.locales');

    foreach ($locales as $locale_code => $locale_name) {

        if ($locale_code == App::getLocale()) {
            continue;
        }

        if (Lang::has('routes.'.$route_name, $locale_code)) {
            $route_uri = $locale_code . '/' . Lang::get('routes.'.$route_name, [], $locale_code);
        }
        else {
            $route_uri = $locale_code . '/' . substr($route_uri, 3);
        }

        Route::get($route_uri, ['as' => 'change_locale_to_'.$locale_code, function(){

        }]);
    }

});
```

`

5. Finally, I use the dummy route in the view I want. $locale_toggle is a Locale eloquent Model that I'm setting in a Middleware for handling the language with a language code route prefix.

`<a href="{{ route('change_locale_to_'.$locale_toggle->code, Route::current()->parameters()) }}" class="dropdown-toggle">`